# Azure Application Proxy, Pre-authentication, SPA - Accessing the access token

Tags: azure, proxy, authorization, token, azure-active-directory

I'm using the Azure Application Proxy with pre-authentication enabled for Azure Active Directory.  Everything is working as expected, getting prompted to login and then being redirected to the site (SPA) via the proxy connector.

**Is there a way to receive the access token in the single page application, so that it can be used to interact with the Graph API to validate membership rights?**

Comment: As I known, you can use ADAL.js to manage authentication with Azure AD.The tokenThe token is cached and the client attaches it to the request as the bearer token when making calls to its Web API back end.More details in this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#single-page-application-spa

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  My question is specific to a web application that is hosted using Azure Application Proxy.  With app proxy, pre-authentication is forced, so the user must sign in with a Microsoft account prior to hitting the server.  Once they hit the server, I want to be able to access user and token context.